# Density of $Y = X^2$

Tags: probability, density-function, change-of-variable

If $f_X(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      \frac{2}{3}x, & \text{if $x \in [-1, 2] $}.\\
      0, & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
  \right.$

What would be the pdf for $Y = X^2$?

I'm thinking $F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^2 \leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_X(\sqrt{y}) - F_X(-\sqrt{y})$. And $F_X (x)= \frac{1}{3}x^2$. So $F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{3}y - \frac{1}{3}y = 0$. But this looks weird and I don't know what is wrong. Could anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: You have to split the interval in two intervals $x\in [-1,1)$ and $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: Any reply, alice?

Comment: So I'm thinking for $x \in [-1, 1]$, that is $y \in [0, 1]$ $F_Y(y) = F_X(\sqrt{y}) - F_X(\sqrt{-y}) = 0$; but for $x \in (1, 2]$, that is $y \in (1, 4]$, $F_Y(y) = P(1 \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_X(\sqrt{y}) - F_X(1) = \frac{1}{3}y - \frac{1}{3} =  \frac{1}{3}y - \frac{1}{3} $?

Comment: I've posted an answer. But  I doubt that $f_x(x)$ is a valid distribtution, since the cdf is not monotone increasing. For instance $F_X(-1)=F_X(1)=0$ and $F(0)=-\frac13$

Comment: there is something wrong with the pdf of $X$...a density is, by definition, always $\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the cdf of $X$ is

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \  x<-1 \\ \frac13 x^2-\frac13, \  -1\leq x \leq 2 \\ 1, \  x>2  \end{cases}$$.

- For $x\in [-1,1]$ we have $F_Y(y) = F_X(\sqrt{y}) - F_X(-\sqrt{y})$.
  The roots of $y$ are   $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$. So you was almost
  right and it has no effect on the final result.

  Then we have $F_Y(y)=\frac13 \left(\sqrt{y}\right)^2-\frac13-(\frac13
     \left(-\sqrt{y}\right)^2-\frac13)=0$
- For $x\in (1,2]$ we have indeed $y\in (1,4]$. Then indeed

  $$F_Y(y)=F(X^2<y)=F(X\leq y^{1/2})=\frac13y-\frac13$$

Therefore the cdf of $Y$ is

$$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases} 0, \  y\leq 1 \\ \frac13 y-\frac13, \  1< y \leq 4 \\ 1, \  y>4  \end{cases}$$.

Comment: OP's post is asking about the pdf though...

Comment: @utobi makes a good point, which can be addressed by differentiating $F_Y$.

Comment: @J.G. I think the  O.P. is able to make her own conclusions. I trust in  her abilities. If she has any questions, she is free to ask.

Comment: I know. I was trying to appease yet subtly downplay the other commenter's concerns. That's why I spoke of differentiating, but not adding it to the answer.

Comment: I wonder if $f_X$ is actually a valid density...if not, this answer may be misleading...

Comment: You can easily check that $F_X(0) = -1/3$, which is a contradiction. So the $f_X$ is not a valid density.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to find the density of $Y$ since $f_X$ is not a valid density. Indeed, for, say, $x=-1/2$, you would have $f_X(-1/2) = -1/3$, which is a contradiction because a density function cannot be negative.

In addition, using $x=0$ in (see @callculus42's answer) $F_X$ we would have $F_X(0) = -1/3$ which is again a contradiction.